# How to add points or markers to line chart using plotly express?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, plotly-express

plotly.express is very convenient to produce nice interactive plots. The code below generates a line chart colored by country.  Now what I need is to add points to the plot. Does anyone know how I can add points to the line chart?

```
import plotly.express as px

gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(gapminder, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### Update:

As of version [`5.2.1`](https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-5-2-1-trendlines-ecdf-plots-markers-on-lines-sharper-webgl-legend-group-titles/55681) you can use `markers=True` in:

```
px.line(df, x='year', y='lifeExp', color='country', markers=True)
```

#### Previous answer for older versions:

Use `fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')`

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
import plotly.express as px

gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(gapminder, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country')

fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Plotly version 5.2.1 this can now be achieved using the `markers` argument of `px.line`. I.e.

```
import plotly.express as px

gapminder = px.data.gapminder().query("continent=='Oceania'")
fig = px.line(gapminder, x="year", y="lifeExp", color='country', markers=True)
fig.show()
```