# Plotly Express line with continuous color scale

Tags: python, plotly

I have the following piece of code

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': x*3,
        'y': list(np.array(x)) + list(np.array(x)**2) + list(np.array(x)**.5),
        'color': list(np.array(x)*0) + list(np.array(x)*0+1) + list(np.array(x)*0+2),
    }
)

for plotting_function in [px.scatter, px.line]:
    fig = plotting_function(
        df,
        x = 'x',
        y = 'y',
        color = 'color',
        title = f'Using {plotting_function.__name__}',
    )
    fig.show()
```

which produces the following two plots:

[image]

[image]

For some reason `px.line` is not producing the continuous color scale that I want, and in [the documentation for `px.scatter`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter) I cannot find how to join the points with lines. How can I produce a plot with a continuous color scale and lines joining the points for each trace?

This is the plot I want to produce:
[image]

Comment: There is a way to set your own line color for line graphs. What does it mean to set a continuous color scale for a line chart? Normally, a changing line graph is represented by a single color. And do I need a color bar?

Comment: The easiest way to do this is as follows. `fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y', color='color', markers=True, color_discrete_sequence=['#0d0887','#d8576b','#f0f921'])`

Comment: A continuous color for a line chart is uncommon but I think it should still be supported. What about drawing trendlines through a very small cluster?

Comment: I don't think it is uncommon. Any "slicing" of a 3D plot results in this, where one of the variables is turned into color. I am surprised that the `plotly.express.line` function does not support this by default.

Comment: Due to the slightly different semantics (if you think about it) of a line plot, I think that using `color_discrete_sequence` (as pointed out by @r-beginners) is the most natural solution and indeed supported for a plotly express line chart!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure this is possible using only `plotly.express`. If you use `px.line`, then you can pass the argument `markers=True` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58637369/how-to-add-points-or-markers-to-line-chart-using-plotly-express), but from the px.line documentation it doesn't look like continuous color scales are supported.

UPDATED ANSWER: in order to have both a legend that groups both the lines and markers together, it's probably simpest to use `go.Scatter` with the argument `mode='lines+markers'`. You'll need to add the traces one at a time (by plotting each unique color portion of the data one at a time) in order to be able to control each line+marker group from the legend.

When plotting these traces, you will need some functions to retrieve the colors of the lines from the continuous color scale because go.Scatter won't know what color your lines are supposed to be unless you specify them - thankfully that has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710057/access-color-from-plotly-color-scale).

Also you won't be able to generate a colorbar adding the markers one color at a time, so to add a colorbar, you can plot all of the markers at once using `go.Scatter`, but use the argument `marker=dict(size=0, color="rgba(0,0,0,0)", colorscale='Plasma', colorbar=dict(thickness=20))` to display a colorbar, but ensure that these duplicate markers are not visible.

Putting all of this together:

```
# import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': x*3,
        'y': list(np.array(x)) + list(np.array(x)**2) + list(np.array(x)**.5),
        'color': list(np.array(x)*0) + list(np.array(x)*0+1) + list(np.array(x)*0+2),
    }
)

# This function allows you to retrieve colors from a continuous color scale
# by providing the name of the color scale, and the normalized location between 0 and 1
# Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62710057/access-color-from-plotly-color-scale

def get_color(colorscale_name, loc):
    from _plotly_utils.basevalidators import ColorscaleValidator
    # first parameter: Name of the property being validated
    # second parameter: a string, doesn't really matter in our use case
    cv = ColorscaleValidator("colorscale", "")
    # colorscale will be a list of lists: [[loc1, "rgb1"], [loc2, "rgb2"], ...] 
    colorscale = cv.validate_coerce(colorscale_name)
    
    if hasattr(loc, "__iter__"):
        return [get_continuous_color(colorscale, x) for x in loc]
    return get_continuous_color(colorscale, loc)
        

# Identical to Adam's answer
import plotly.colors
from PIL import ImageColor

def get_continuous_color(colorscale, intermed):
    """
    Plotly continuous colorscales assign colors to the range [0, 1]. This function computes the intermediate
    color for any value in that range.

    Plotly doesn't make the colorscales directly accessible in a common format.
    Some are ready to use:
    
        colorscale = plotly.colors.PLOTLY_SCALES["Greens"]

    Others are just swatches that need to be constructed into a colorscale:

        viridis_colors, scale = plotly.colors.convert_colors_to_same_type(plotly.colors.sequential.Viridis)
        colorscale = plotly.colors.make_colorscale(viridis_colors, scale=scale)

    :param colorscale: A plotly continuous colorscale defined with RGB string colors.
    :param intermed: value in the range [0, 1]
    :return: color in rgb string format
    :rtype: str
    """
    if len(colorscale) < 1:
        raise ValueError("colorscale must have at least one color")

    hex_to_rgb = lambda c: "rgb" + str(ImageColor.getcolor(c, "RGB"))

    if intermed <= 0 or len(colorscale) == 1:
        c = colorscale[0][1]
        return c if c[0] != "#" else hex_to_rgb(c)
    if intermed >= 1:
        c = colorscale[-1][1]
        return c if c[0] != "#" else hex_to_rgb(c)

    for cutoff, color in colorscale:
        if intermed > cutoff:
            low_cutoff, low_color = cutoff, color
        else:
            high_cutoff, high_color = cutoff, color
            break

    if (low_color[0] == "#") or (high_color[0] == "#"):
        # some color scale names (such as cividis) returns:
        # [[loc1, "hex1"], [loc2, "hex2"], ...]
        low_color = hex_to_rgb(low_color)
        high_color = hex_to_rgb(high_color)

    return plotly.colors.find_intermediate_color(
        lowcolor=low_color,
        highcolor=high_color,
        intermed=((intermed - low_cutoff) / (high_cutoff - low_cutoff)),
        colortype="rgb",
    )

fig = go.Figure()

## add the lines+markers
for color_val in df.color.unique():
    color_val_normalized = (color_val - min(df.color)) / (max(df.color) - min(df.color))
    # print(f"color_val={color_val}, color_val_normalized={color_val_normalized}")
    df_subset = df[df['color'] == color_val]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=df_subset['x'],
        y=df_subset['y'],
        mode='lines+markers',
        marker=dict(color=get_color('Plasma', color_val_normalized)),
        name=f"line+marker {color_val}",
        legendgroup=f"line+marker {color_val}"
    ))

## add invisible markers to display the colorbar without displaying the markers
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['x'],
    y=df['y'],
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=0, 
        color="rgba(0,0,0,0)", 
        colorscale='Plasma', 
        cmin=min(df.color),
        cmax=max(df.color),
        colorbar=dict(thickness=40)
    ),
    showlegend=False
))

fig.update_layout(
    legend=dict(
    yanchor="top",
    y=0.99,
    xanchor="left",
    x=0.01),
    yaxis_range=[min(df.y)-2,max(df.y)+2]
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it possible to somehow link each line to whatever `legendgroup` it has the corresponding scatter plot? So I can enable/disable both line and markers as a unique entity.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that you can't have a legend for continuous color when using px.line - according to the documentation on legends [here](https://plotly.com/python/legend/#trace-types-legends-and-color-bars). For px.line you need to choose between discrete colors (which supports a legend) or continuous colors (which supports a colorbar)

Comment: However, if you add each line and marker as an individual trace, I think you may be able to achieve the desired chart using `plotly.graph_objects` exclusively - I can get back to you on this

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this using only 2 more parameters in `px.line`:

- `markers=True`
- `color_discrete_sequence=my_plotly_continuous_sequence`

The complete code would look something like this (Note the list slicing `[::4]` so that the colors are well spaced):

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x': x * 3,
        'y': list(np.array(x)) + list(np.array(x) ** 2) + list(np.array(x) ** .5),
        'color': list(np.array(x) * 0) + list(np.array(x) * 0 + 1) + list(np.array(x) * 0 + 2),
    }
)

fig = px.line(
    df,
    x='x',
    y='y',
    color='color',
    color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.sequential.Plasma[::4],
    markers=True,
    template='plotly'
)
fig.show()
```

This produces the following output.

[image: Plot]

In case you have more lines than the colors present in the colormap, you can construct a custom colorscale so that you get one complete sequence instead of a cycling sequence:

```
rgb = px.colors.convert_colors_to_same_type(px.colors.sequential.RdBu)[0]

colorscale = []
n_steps = 4  # Control the number of colors in the final colorscale
for i in range(len(rgb) - 1):
    for step in np.linspace(0, 1, n_steps):
        colorscale.append(px.colors.find_intermediate_color(rgb[i], rgb[i + 1], step, colortype='rgb'))

fig = px.line(df_e, x='temperature', y='probability', color='year', color_discrete_sequence=colorscale, height=900)
fig.show()
```

[image: Plot 2]

Answer (score 3):

Building on [@manuel-montoya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10649437/manuel-montoya)  answer, the colormap generation code may be simplified using built in `plotly.express.colors.sample_colorscale` function, for example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

NO_LINES = 24
X_RANGE = 64
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "c": np.arange(NO_LINES).repeat(X_RANGE),
        "x": np.tile(np.arange(X_RANGE), NO_LINES),
        "y": np.random.rand(X_RANGE * NO_LINES),
    }
)
df["y"] = 0.2 * df["x"] ** 1.2 + 2 * df["c"] + df["y"]

color_variable = "c"

myscale = px.colors.sample_colorscale(
    colorscale=px.colors.sequential.RdBu,
    samplepoints=len(df[color_variable].unique()),
    low=0.0,
    high=1.0,
    colortype="rgb",
)

px.line(
    df,
    x="x",
    y="y",
    markers=True,
    color=color_variable,
    color_discrete_sequence=myscale,
).show()
```

Result can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz7R9.png). It does not display colormap, hovewer, but the code is much simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: this is the cleanest and most generalisable answer